# dyld: Library not loaded zendesk

Tags: ios, sdk, zendesk

On adding Zendesk to a project in my app, the app compiles fine, but on launching it, the app crashes with the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/ZendeskCoreSDK.framework/ZendeskCoreSDK
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/54F97442-93B5-469E-A069-5F91C4689249/App.app/App
  Reason: image not found
```

I am quite sure I have followed all the instructions, but this just refuses to work

Answer (score 0):

:)

In your project, goto build phases and the embedded frameworks section, find the 3 Zendesk frameworks in the file list and drag them into this section.

it will work now. :)